# Не работает WebHook Telegram

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

я пишу бот для Telegram. Пишу на yii2. Установил плагин - он работает, то есть я могу например отправить сообщение. Но мне надо что бы когда кто то пишет сообщение - ему сразу приходил ответ. Устанавливаю webhook -

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot424075598:AAEx_5YTxUVdeL123123123_5X3tmHtiVKA/setWebhook?url=https://site.ru/bot
```

В ответ получаю

```
{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook is already set"}
```

И по адресу https://site.ru/bot пишу обработчик, который присылает ответ. Если просто открыть ссылку - сообщение присылается, если написать боту - нет.

Не могу понять, где косяк, так как по идее должно работать

Comment: Что приходит по `getWebhookinfo`? Вероятно, `500`, `405` ошибки.

Comment: У меня аналогичная проблема, открыл тему, уже второй день молчек(